# How to Reset Newly Added Form Inputs

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfml

edits:

1. removed code that was unnecessary...

2. Clarified desired solution and added reset button HTML.

I've seen various methods used to reset a form but I add content to a blank div (id = "unitPulled") via AJAX so, methods similar to the following will not work:

```
document.forms[0].reset();
```

My goal is to reset the entire form when a user hits a reset button.

How do I go about tackling this issue? Would the DOM have to be reloaded?

HTML for button:

```
<button id="reset" name="reset" class="btn btn-default" type="reset">Clear</button>
```

Javascript:

```
/* Below is for auto-updating of initial and number */
var oXmlHttp

function showUnits(str) // Change function name
{
    var url = "ajax.cfm?&lic_plate=" + str // Change URL
    oXmlHttp = GetHttpObject(stateChanged)
    oXmlHttp.open("GET", url, true)
    oXmlHttp.send(null)
}

// Below is where new elements are added:
function stateChanged() {
    if (oXmlHttp.readyState == 4 || oXmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {
       document.getElementById("unitPulled").innerHTML = oXmlHttp.responseText; // Change ID
       document.getElementById("lic_plate").focus();

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to remove all content of the div?

Comment: Is the newly added field inside the `form[0]`?

Comment: Keshav - Removing all the content or resetting the newly added values for each input would be ideal. Rejith - Yes, the newly added field are inside the form, within the div "unitPulled"

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in you `function stateChanged()`

```
function stateChanged() {
    if (oXmlHttp.readyState == 4 || oXmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {
       document.getElementById("unitPulled").innerHTML = oXmlHttp.responseText; // Change ID
       document.getElementById("myForm").reset(); 
       document.getElementById("lic_plate").focus();
    }
}
```

Please put your form id instead of myForm. Let me know if this is not working as form value will be reset after ajax call.

Comment: I wouldn't want to reset the form inside the stateChanged function. It would be when a button is pressed. Also, this method doesn't make it clear when a button is pressed.